# how to get response from the xml web Api

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have XML Web API like this

http://test/REST?hiInstanceId=7

XML parameters

<request_info>SALE</request_info><location_id>36</location_id>
<from_dt>01-JUN-22</from_dt><to_dt>10-JUN-22</to_dt>

how to get the response from the XML web API?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  How are you accessing the API?  Generally whatever access the API receives the response.  What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://test/REST?hiInstanceId=7") as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<params><request_info>SALE</request_info><location_id>36</location_id><from_dt>01-JUN-22</from_dt><to_dt>10-JUN-22</to_dt></params>");
            string rawXml = doc.OuterXml; I tried like this I want response from the API

Comment: A Google search for "httpwebrequest example" finds lots of examples...

Answer (score 3):

> how to get response from the xml web Api

To make the Asp.net Core API return the XML format response. We need to configure XML formatters implemented using XmlSerializer, call AddXmlSerializerFormatters:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Then, in the API controller, use [the `[Produces]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-6.0#specify-a-format) to specify a format.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodoController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("application/xml")]
    public TestModel GetCustomers( )
    {
        return new TestModel()
        {
            request_info = "Sale",
            location_id = 36,
            from_dt = "01-JUN-22",
            to_dt = "10-JUN-22"
        };
    }
}
```

Then, use the following code to call the API method and get the XML response:

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://localhost:44374/api/todo"));
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
httpRequest.Method = "Get";
using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        string xml = (new StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd(); //get the XML response

        //Using XMLSerializer to convert the XML response to the object.
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestModel));
        StringReader rdr = new StringReader(xml);
        var result = (TestModel)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
    }
}
```

The debug screenshot like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of an MVC Api implemented using .Net Core 7 that produces an XML response with the header

```
// Controller
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult GetXmlResponse()
    {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();


    // Create the header of the response
    xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", string.Empty));

    // Create the response body
    var rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("MyResponse");
    xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
    rootNode.SetAttribute("version", "1.0");

    // Add other elements to the response
    // ...

    return Content(xmlDoc.OuterXml, "text/xml");
    }

}
```